# maven compilation error : package com.jayway.restassured does not exist

Tags: maven, rest-assured

I created maven project in eclipse and also add dependency Rest-Assured into pom.xml file. When right click project in Eclipse to 'Run As' > Maven test, it pops out follow error

error: package com.jayway.restassured does not exist

Here are snippet of my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

I also change scope 'complile' to 'test' and got same error.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project dpmatest: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

On another project, by change scope 'test' to 'compile' I have no issue to compile with Rest-Assured package.

Can someone help me? and explain difference between scope 'test' vs 'compile'.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

See [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism, Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

- **compile**
  This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
- **test**
  This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases.